# Blocklayered module not working prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, blocklayered

I have a bug on my prestashop website that i don't know how to fix.
My blocklayered module is not working... I've tried refreshing cache and indexes and also restored the module with original one but it's not working... I've also setted permissions to 777 for all the folders and files of the module...
Here is the error line:

```
v_24_2e5bc2f239b0cac64f2bff372a426d98.js:4 GET https://www.bobo-sport.fr/modules/blocklayered/blocklayered-ajax.php?layered_category_12=12&id_category_layered=13&_=1532013197475 500 ()
```

You can see the problem on this page for exemple: https://www.bobo-sport.fr/13-soins

Could you please have a look to my problem?
Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: Enable error reporting.

Comment: debug mode is now activated. When i activate it it's still not working and i have no code error in browser console...

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Call to private method BlockLayered::getSelectedFilters() from context 'BlockLayeredOverride' in .../override/modules/blocklayered/blocklayered.php:10`. You have override of the module installed that's calling a private method outside the class. While you reinstalled the original module, override is still there causing problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TheDrot ! I've delated it and it's working now! Thank you!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a silly resolution but we had the same issue.

**screenshot of blank line**

[image]

Found the fix by total fluke.

In blocklayered.php remove the blank line on the top of the file. 
Some apache configs manage this others not. Sometimes there is a hidden ascii value in there that throws an error of headers already sent.

One of our clever engineers spotted this after hours of searching. 
Nearly killed us.

Hope this helps.